# Upgrading the JRE version from 8u241 to 8u261 is removing namespaces(xmlns) tags from xml file while writing back using LSSerializer

Tags: java, java-8

Recently Upgraded the JRE version from 8u241 to 8u261 is breaking my code of writing back dom XML to file. Its removing all the xmlns tags from the xml document.

Below is the code I am using:-

```
final DOMImplementationRegistry registry = DOMImplementationRegistry.newInstance();
final DOMImplementationLS impl = (DOMImplementationLS) registry.getDOMImplementation("LS");
final LSSerializer writer = impl.createLSSerializer();
writer.getDomConfig().setParameter("format-pretty-print", Boolean.TRUE);
final LSOutput output = impl.createLSOutput();
output.setByteStream(out);
writer.write(document, output);
```

Can someone please help me to fix this issue?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others. Also show the output/result which was generated with the version 8u241 and the output/result which was generated with the updated version 8u261.